# How to find psycopg2 version number

Tags: python, psycopg2

I installed psycopg2 on my Ubuntu Natty machine using apt-get. Now, I would like to know its version number. Can someone tell what the method to find version number for such python packages is.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since you installed it with the package manager, you can get the version from the command line with this command:

```
dpkg -s psycopg2
```

Alternatively you can get the version from using `pip`, if you have that installed

```
pip freeze | grep psycopg2
```

Or just run a python command to tell you:

```
python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"
```

### Output examples:

```
λ > pip freeze | grep psycopg2
psycopg2==2.4.4

λ > python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"
2.4.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)
```

Comment: I like 1 line python commands. Thanks for that: $ python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"

Comment: getting this error : `AttributeError: module 'psycopg2' has no attribute '__version__'` when using `python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"`. Why ?

Comment: @kabrice That's strange - it's definitely still there in the latest version of it. You wouldn't happen to be using some kind of funky unicode `_` characters or not using double `_` are you?

Comment: for those who are using python 3, mac m1 pro.   
python3 -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"
output: 
2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)

Answer (score 4):

You can check the `__version__` attribute on the module, from within Python:

```
>>> psycopg2.__version__
'2.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)'
```

Comment: python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"